Disable swipe gestures ubuntu
Hello I am trying to make a kiosk on ubuntu 20.04.
The problem that I am having is that when I run the kiosk mode, with some gestures on the touch screen it takes it out.
For example, if I make the gesture on the left edge by sliding my finger from left to right, it shows me the activities (use the gnome extension) but disables the scroll.
The other gesture that is giving me problems is the swipe from the top to the bottom (resets the window to a smaller size)
Any idea how to fix it?
